# HTML -> PHP - Button not work after change dropdown to list in form

Tags: php, html, forms

> I don't know if my title is right or not, may someone edit that to the right things

**Trouble :**

I've created a dropdown in form, and it's working like this:

[dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqOz3.png)

then now I want to change the dropdown form to show each dropdown data without dropdown like this :

[list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaPq5.png)

but the button not working after I change the form,

here's a piece of my code to display and execute :

```
    <form method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ia">Alternatif</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="ia" name="ia">
                <?php
                $stmt3 = $pgn1->readAll();
                while ($row3 = $stmt3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    extract($row3);
                    echo "<option value='{$id_alternatif}'>{$nama_alternatif}</option>";
                }
                ?>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ik">Kriteria</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="ik" name="ik">
                <?php
                $stmt2 = $pgn2->readAll();
                while ($row2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    extract($row2);
                    echo "<option value='{$id_kriteria}'>{$nama_kriteria}</option>";
                }
                ?>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nn">Nilai</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nn" name="nn">
            </select>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Simpan</button>
          <button type="button" onclick="location.href='rangking.php'" class="btn btn-success">Kembali</button>
        </form>

        //for display item as list im change <label for="ik">Kriteria</label> code
        <div class="form-group">
            <form class="form-control" id="ik" name="ik">
                <?php
                $stmt2 = $pgn2->readAll();
                while ($row2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    extract($row2);
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $id_kriteria; ?>"><?php echo $nama_kriteria; ?></option>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nn" name="nn">
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </form>
          </div>
```

I use this code to execute the button in same file as form file :

```
<?php
if($_POST){

    include_once 'includes/rangking.inc.php';
    $eks = new rangking($db);

    $eks->ia = $_POST['ia'];
    $eks->ik = $_POST['ik'];
    $eks->nn = $_POST['nn'];

    if($eks->insert()){
?>
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Berhasil Tambah Data!</strong> Tambah lagi atau <a href="rangking.php">lihat semua data</a>.
</div>
<?php
    }

    else{
?>
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Gagal Tambah Data!</strong> Terjadi kesalahan, coba sekali lagi.
</div>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

anyone can help me please??

***EDIT***

here's my code of `if($eks->insert())` in execute the button :

```
function insert(){

        $query = "insert into ".$this->table_name." values(?,?,?,'','')";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->ia);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $this->ik);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $this->nn);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hello, can you explain better? 
i saw you have 2 forms. your submit button is in first form and changed list is in second form is this right? the button will work only within the form it is.

Comment: @BARNI the point is, why my first form is work to save the value, but when i change form interface to be like 2nd form, the button not working (no alert showing)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing button type to 'submit'.

`<button type="submit" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  <strong>Berhasil Tambah Data!</strong> Tambah lagi atau <a href="rangking.php">lihat semua data</a></button>`

Comment: still not working, becuase if the issue about the button type, my first image won't save the value

Comment: ok. and button redirects to which location? did you add any location to it?

Comment: I still didn't get what you want. But see my edit, I have changed closing button tag to the end.